# How to modify the signature of a function dynamically

Tags: python-3.x, arguments, abstract-syntax-tree, python-internals

I am writing a framework in Python. When a user declares a function, they do:

```
def foo(row, fetch=stuff, query=otherStuff)

def bar(row, query=stuff)

def bar2(row)
```

When the backend sees query= value, it executes the function with the query argument depending on value. This way the function has access to the result of something done by the backend in its scope.

Currently I build my arguments each time by checking whether query, fetch and the other items are None, and launching it with a set of args that exactly matches what the user asked for. Otherwise I got the "got an unexpected keyword argument" error. This is the code in the backend:

```
#fetch and query is something computed by the backend
if fetch= None and query==None:
    userfunction(row)
elif fetch==None:
    userunction (row, query=query)
elif query == None:
    userfunction (row, fetch=fetch)
else:
    userfunction (row,fetch=fetch,query=query)
```

This is not good; for each additional "service" the backend offers, I need to write all the combinations with the previous ones.

Instead of that I would like to primarily take the function and manually add a named parameter, before executing it, removing all the unnecessary code that does these checks. Then the user would just use the stuff it really wanted.

I don't want the user to have to modify the function by adding stuff it doesn't want (nor do I want them to specify a `kwarg` every time).

So I would like an example of this if this is doable, a function `addNamedVar(name, function)` that adds the variable `name` to the function `function`.

I want to do that that way because the users functions are called a lot of times, meaning that it would trigger me to, for example, create a dict of the named var of the function (with inspect) and then using `**dict`. I would really like to just modify the function once to avoid any kind of overhead.

Comment: Could you explain why the -1?

Comment: After some search I think it's maybe doable with the ast module. Modifying the functionDef nodes. I am not that sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed doable in AST and that's what I am gonna do because this solution will suit better for my use case . However you could do what I asked more simply by having a function cloning approach like the code snippet I show. Note that this code return the same functions with different defaults values. You can use this code as example to do whatever you want.
This works for python3

```py
def copyTransform(f, name, **args):
    signature=inspect.signature(f)
    params= list(signature.parameters)
    numberOfParam= len(params)
    numberOfDefault= len(f.__defaults__)
    listTuple= list(f.__defaults__)

    for key,val in args.items():
        toChangeIndex = params.index(key, numberOfDefault)
        if toChangeIndex:
            listTuple[toChangeIndex- numberOfDefault]=val

    newTuple= tuple(listTuple)
    oldCode=f.__code__

    newCode= types.CodeType(
        oldCode.co_argcount,             #   integer
        oldCode.co_kwonlyargcount,       #   integer
        oldCode.co_nlocals,              #   integer
        oldCode.co_stacksize,            #   integer
        oldCode.co_flags,                #   integer
        oldCode.co_code,                 #   bytes
        oldCode.co_consts,               #   tuple
        oldCode.co_names,                #   tuple
        oldCode.co_varnames,             #   tuple
        oldCode.co_filename,             #   string
        name,                            #   string
        oldCode.co_firstlineno,          #   integer
        oldCode.co_lnotab,               #   bytes
        oldCode.co_freevars,             #   tuple
        oldCode.co_cellvars              #   tuple
        )

    newFunction=types.FunctionType(newCode, f.__globals__, name, newTuple, f.__closure__)
    newFunction.__qualname__=name #also needed for serialization
```

You need to do that weird stuff with the names if you want to Pickle your clone function.