# How to dynamically change the signature of a function without modifying the AST?

Tags: python

I'm writing an equivalent of Python's `@dataclass` and I'm trying to monkeypatch the constructor of decorated classes. My decorator is currently as follows:

```py
def decorator(decorated_class):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        # do stuff
    decorated_class.__init__ = __init__
    return decorated_class
```

What I want to be able to do is dynamically set the arguments of the newly created `__init__` method based on the class attributes. For example say we have a class `Person`:

```py
@decorator
class Person:
    name: str
    age: int
```

My desired behaviour would be to dynamically generate the following constructor and monkey-patching it as I'm currently already doing in the decorator

```py
def __init__(self, name, age):
    self.name = name
    self.age = age
```

This behaviour is probably achievable by messing around with the AST at runtime but it obviously comes at a performance price which I would like to avoid. Is there any way of doing this by (for example) interacting directly with the `function` object?

Note: the solution provided by [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56546854/how-to-modify-the-signature-of-a-function-dynamically) is poorly described and doesn't run.

Comment: `dataclasses` itself just uses `exec` for that.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica that's quite straightforward, are there no security concerns with that approach?

Comment: You have to be very careful about how you do it. One particular concern would be what happens if someone calls your decorator on a dynamically-generated class, which might have entries in its `__dict__` or `__annotations__` that aren't legal Python identifiers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `setattr` and `*args/**kwargs` to do it without messing up with the AST. From your explanation, I assume you don't care about the original `__init__` function.

The following code generates a `__init__` function tailored for the class members:

```py
def decorator(cls):
    # Find out the attributes. Standard class attributes have priority over annotations
    attributes = [name for name in cls.__dict__ if not name.startswith('_')]
    if '__annotations__' in cls.__dict__:
        for attr_name in cls.__dict__['__annotations__']:
            if attr_name not in attributes:
                attributes.append(attr_name)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for attr_name, value in zip(attributes, args):
            setattr(self, attr_name, value)
        for tentative_name, value in kwargs.items():
            if tentative_name in attributes:
                setattr(self, tentative_name, value)
    cls.__init__ = __init__
    return cls
```

It basically searches for entries in `__dict__` and `__annotations__` that do not start with a `_` and allows them to be passed to the constructor. I excluded entries starting with a single `_` because they typically wouldn't be set from the constructor. Here are some tests:

```py
@decorator
class Person:
    name: str
    age: int

john = Person('John', 32)
assert john.name == 'John'
assert john.age == 32

mary = Person(name='Mary', age=18)
assert mary.name == 'Mary'
assert mary.age == 18
```

This also works for classes with default attributes:

```py
@decorator
class OtherPerson:
    name = 'John Doe'
    age = 21

mustafa = OtherPerson('Mustafa', 15)
assert mustafa.name == 'Mustafa'
assert mustafa.age == 15

yuko = OtherPerson(name='Yuko', age=71)
assert yuko.name == 'Yuko'
assert yuko.age == 71
```

I think it is possible to wrap the original `__init__` but I don't believe there is anything very intelligent that can be done about the original arguments.